# JaCoCo Functional Test Coverage on SONAR

Tags: maven, code-coverage, sonarqube, jacoco

I am working on to get Functional Test Coverage using JaCoCo and SONAR for a java based application.

My Requirement:

1. Get Functional Test Coverage.
2. Publish the Functional Test Coverage results to SONAR(pass on the jacoco.exec file to SONAR)

Below is the set up I did:

1. Set up instances on my DVL(development box) and make the system up and running.
2. In the /bin directory of the instances, I am including jacoco agent in the CATALINA_OPTS variable with below configuration:
   vim catalina.sh
   export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -javaagent:${XYZ_ROOT}/WEB-INF/lib/org.jacoco.agent-0.5.8.201206210517.jar=includes=com.xyz.xx.*,excludes=com.xyz.xx.webclient.command.*UIBean*,output=tcpclient,address=lxdm379m7.xyz.com,port=9000"

   (lxdm379m7.xyz.com is my sonar server and 9000 is the port number)
3. Now restarted the server, And the server is up.
4. I do manual testing on my AUT which is on my DVL. Hit pages back and forth.

My Issue:
Not able to generate the jacoco.exec file.

Help I need:

1. Why is the jacoco.exec file not generated.
2. If it is generated, where can I find it? and how to pass it on to SONAR ?

Any help or clue on this is appreciated.

Comment: Hi could you any help me out pls.

Comment: Hi there, can someone help me with this nightmare.

Comment: Possible duplicate (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35891163/it-code-coverage-with-sonar/35899515#35899515)