# IT code coverage with sonar

Tags: maven, sonarqube, integration-testing, jacoco

I have the following task at hand:

-- find IT code coverage for a project

Given situation:

-- IT code resides in a repository separate to the actual production code

-- Production code that the tests were created for reside in more than one git repository.

-- all of the above uses maven and are written in Java.

I have tried following different tutorial and blogs but couldnt find a simpler answer.

Can anyone either point me towards the right resource or give me hints for a kick start?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: maybe [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) is the right place for your question.

Comment: @Ulrich this question is a poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see [Where to start?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6367/31260) Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer. I will post example with UT (IT is the same thing just not at the same place in the maven livecycle build, and instead of the surefire plugin its the failsafe plugin)

Lets say we use JaCoCo for the code coverage agent.
In my Parent pom, in the profile section (it is a multi module project)

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.15</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.7.4.201502262128</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
                                <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>post-unit-test</id>
                            <phase>test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

Now when we build our maven project, we add the profile to inject the JaCoCo Agent

```
clean install -Psonar-coverage
```

Then we may tell sonar to analyse our project and to use the JaCoCo report with the following command

```
mvn org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.4:sonar -Dsonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports -Dsonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco -Dsonar.forceAnalysis=true -Dsonar.jacoco.reportMissing.force.zero=true -Dsonar.binaries=target/classes -Dsonar.junit.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports -Dsonar.jacoco.reportPath=target/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec -Dsonar.jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:<YOUR SONAR INSTALLATION DB> -Dsonar.host.url=<YOUR SONAR INSTALLATION>
```